# Intellij auto optimize imports for Go

Tags: intellij-idea, go, intellij-14

I have Intellij ultimate version **14.1.4**. How do I enable optimizing imports automatically with each save for **"Go"**? 
In **Settings->Editor->General->Auto Imports**, I see options for **Java/python/scala** but not for **Go**. I have the Go plugin installed already. But this unused import compile error is a noise. I want to enable automatic optimizing of imports to avoid `CTRL+ALT+O` combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is not yet available for the Go plugin, that's why you don't see any options there / it doesn't work automatically.

You might want to watch [this issue](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/1268) or maybe [this PR](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/pull/1807) to get notified when they will be fixed.

Meanwhile, you can use the **Code** -> **Goimports file** functionality and maybe assign it a shortcut of your own preference as it doesn't have one by default. For this to work you will need to have [goimports](http://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports) installed and in your system's PATH.